# JavaScript/jQuery: Passing multiple parameters to a POST request in an API

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, post, request

I'm having a bit of trouble managing an API request for a new project. I'm trying to practice making POST requests, and I wanted to pass multiple parameters in one POST. So far, I've tried making a for loop that loops through an array to make multiple requests, but that doesn't seem to be working. I've handled simple GET requests before, but I can't seem to figure out to pass multiple parameters to a post without rewriting the whole thing.

Here's what I have so far:

```
let URL = "www.exampleapi.com";
```

Here's the array I'm working with, they are supposed to be dogs in a kennel.

```
let dogArray = [
{"id": 1,
"name": "Max" },
{"id": 2,
"name": "Jack"},
{"id": 3,
"name": "Bones" }
];
```

The kennel the dogs are in currently has an id of 777

```
let kennelId = 777;
```

The POST request for this API requires the kennelId and the dogId (dogArray.id), so I wanted to write a function that loops though the dogArray and records the individual ids.

```
function getDogsInKennel(kennelId, dogArray) {

for (let i = 0; i < dogArray.length; i++) {
        //the API would assign a different dogId every time it looped through
        dogId = dogArray[i].id;
    }

fetch(URL, {
        method: 'POST',
        body: JSON.stringify(({ dogId: dogId, kennelId: kennelId })),
        headers:{
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        }
    }).then(result => result.json())
}

getDogsInKennel(kennelId, dogArray);
```

As you can tell, this method isn't working. Should I scrap the entire function and try something else, or is there a way this can be rewritten to make multiple POST calls using the same array?

Comment: This is probably obvious, but make sure the types of `dogId` and `kennelId` are the correct types (like number, string, object, etc.). Also take a look at [`$.post`](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/). That might be easier for you (it is in my opinion)

Comment: Don't you think your fetch code should be inside the loop?

Answer (score 0):

The main issue I am seeing is that you are not placing your code to *POST* inside the *for* look, so it will only *POST* once, using the last dogId assigned by the *for* loop

Additionally, you are not doing anything with the returned data after converting the result to JSON. If you checkout the fetch documentation [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch#Uploading_JSON_data) you can see that you need to add another *.then* to handle the returned value. 
So you would end up with something a bit more like this for your function:

```
function getDogsInKennel(kennelId, dogArray) {

for (let i = 0; i < dogArray.length; i++) {
    dogId = dogArray[i].id;

    fetch(URL, {
      method: 'POST',
      body: JSON.stringify(({ dogId: dogId, kennelId: kennelId })),
      headers:{
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      }
    }).then(result => result.json())
    .then((data) => {
      // Process the result here 
    })
}
```

The *.then* is only needed if you are doing something with the result, like handling a success message/status.

I'm also not sure if you are intending to use promises to do this or not, the fetch method is promise-based. Something simpler to use may be *$.post* available in jQuery ([more about that here](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/))

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps:

```
function getDogsInKennel(kennelId, dogArray) {
let dogIds = []
for (let i = 0; i < dogArray.length; i++) {
        dogIds.push(dogArray[i].id);
    }

fetch(URL, {
        method: 'POST',
        body: JSON.stringify(({ dogId: dogIds, kennelId: kennelId })),
        headers:{
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        }
    }).then(result => result.json()).then((data) => {
      console.log(data)
    })
}

getDogsInKennel(kennelId, dogArray);
```